# How to play video in listview onitem click in the same view?

Tags: android, listview, onitemclick

How can I display the video in same view of `ListView` when I click the item of `ListView` like the image below?

[image]

Comment: So you want to create a `ListView` where all the items are videos or..?

Comment: Displaying images in the listview,when i click on image that will be hide and shows the video at the same view.And also when i scroll the listview the video will not be stop.

Comment: Do you have a list of URLs for the videos and/or a list of image thumbnails?

Comment: yes i have list of video urls and images

Answer (score 0):

On the `ListView` with the images you can add a `setOnItemClickListener`
Then when `onItemClick` is called you can retrieve the URL of the video you are trying to play according to the position in the list like this

```
String videoUrl = videoUrls[position];
```

From here you can open a new `Activity`/`Dialog`; whichever you prefer to display the video and add the URL as an argument using something similar to this:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("URL", videoUrl );
```

Then assign it using `setArguments(args)` to your `Dialog` if you have chosen a `Dialog` or using `putExtra` if you have chosen an `Activity`.
From here you can get the video URL and display it.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer:
Fragments

on listitem click switch the listview to your player fragment.

Comment: but how can i refresh the views